# How to simulate Azure Cosmos DB and Azure Redis regional failure scenarios using reverse proxy mechanism?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage, reverse-proxy, azure-redis-cache

To simulate regional failure, using Fiddler below custom rules has been created under "OnBeforeResponse" function.

I can able to intercept http calls to **Azure storage account** successfully and able to inject failed response where as https calls to Azure Cosmos DB calls I can't able to intercept why? Am I missing anything?

I can't even able to intercept Azure redis related calls but I can understand the reason that Redis is not using HTTP communication but why I cant able to intercept https calls to Azure Cosmos DB calls, no idea and needs expertise opinion.

Also need advice on how to intercept Redis calls and to inject artificial failure response code? to simulate Azure Redis regional failure situation.

```
         static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
                if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304) {
                    oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
                }
    
                // az storage account call manipulated response
                if (oSession.hostname == "mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net")
                {
                    oSession.responseCode = 503;
                }
    
                // az cosmos db account call manipulated response -- not working
                if (oSession.hostname == "mydocdb.documents.azure.com")
                {
                    oSession.responseCode = 503;
                }
                // az redis call manipulated response -- not working
                if (oSession.hostname == "myrediscache.redis.cache.windows.net")
                {
                    oSession.responseCode = 503;
                }
```

[image: Sample network traffic captured via fiddler:]

P.S: At the moment we are using cosmos db SDK v2 whether cosmos db SDK v2 by default uses HTTP or TCP? as per fiddler it is HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Redis does but you can do failover testing in Cosmos by manually failing a region over to your secondary region. This can be done in the portal or with PS, CLI, Templates or using Azure Management SDK.

Can learn more here, [Perform a manual failover on a Cosmos DB account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-database-account#manual-failover)

Comment: Our cosmosdb account is multi write & no failover scenario applicable for multi write cosmosdb account isn't it?

Comment: The only way to simulate a fail over in a multi-master account is to use a firewall rule on the VM  you are testing from. I have a sample of how to do this in this repo here, https://github.com/markjbrown/cosmos-global-distribution-demos